# How to Order Posts by Custom Fields?

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

Can someone tell me why this is not working:

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => '2,39,30',
    'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',  
    'meta_key' => 'album_rating',  
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I would like to order the posts according to their rating (Its working) AND alphabetically (Not working)

Thanks

Comment: The first doesn't work because you are making multiple orderby and order. Look into this link it might help http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/Multiple-orderby-and-order-options-in-WP-Query-td36938.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var_dump` your `$args` arguments:

```
array(4) {
  ["cat"]=>
  string(7) "2,39,30"
  ["orderby"]=>
  string(14) "meta_value_num"
  ["order"]=>
  string(4) "DESC"
  ["meta_key"]=>
  string(12) "album_rating"
}
```

The second time you use a key, you overwrite the first time. You cannot build the array like that.

The `orderby` parameter will take a space separated string, so this is closer:

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => '2,39,30',
    'orderby' => 'title meta_value_num', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'album_rating',  
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

But as before, you can't use the same key twice and you are still trying to use `order` twice. If you look at the SQL, you will see that only the last value is used and it is applied to the last `orderby` value.

```
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title,wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Still closer...

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => '2,39,30',
    'orderby' => 'title meta_value_num', 
    'meta_key' => 'album_rating',  
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

And that *might* get you what you want. To be sure though, you will need a filter:

```
function alter_order_wpse_117098($orderby) {
  remove_action('posts_orderby','alter_order_wpse_117098');
  $order = str_replace(',',' ASC, ',$orderby);
  return $order;
}
add_action(
  'posts_orderby',
  'alter_order_wpse_117098'
);
```

Add that filter immediately before the query in question. It will remove itself so shouldn't mess up any other queries.

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for your interest.  I have added the following filter:  add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'alter_order_wpse_117098' ); 
 $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); + your function.  Now the posts are being ordered by title (ASC) and not by album_rating.  Is my filter faulty?   I must be messing something up (me newbie !)   Thank you

Comment: Then swap the values in the `orderby` argument. The code above will do what you need, even if it needs tweaking to get the details exactly right.